# How to display image from db in wpf using Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

I have an image in a SQL Server column of type `image` and I want to display it in `Image` control in a WPF application.

Here's my code:

```
 ProjectDBDataContext db = new ProjectDBDataContext();

 var film = from f in db.Films
            where f.id == int.Parse(idFilm.Text)
            select f;
```

Now I'm getting a binary type `film.First().img` but I really have know idea what do do with this.

Please, any help

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope u get your answer this code for loading picture form folder:

in ListView Add ItemTemplate

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Width="110" BorderBrush="#FFD1D1D1" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" Background="Black">
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Width="100" 
                                   Height="85" Stroke="#FF818181">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Icon}"/>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFF0E6CB" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

this code for loading data

```
 string AppPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string targetPath = Path.Combine(AppPath, @"Sources\Pictures\", FileNo);
        if (Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            var ListPath = Directory.GetFiles(targetPath, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
            List<ExplorerData> Items = new List<ExplorerData>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ListPath.Count; i++)
            {
                var ImageName = Path.GetFileName(ListPath[i]);
                Items.Add(new ExplorerData()
                {
                    ID = i + 1,
                    Name = ImageName.Remove(ImageName.Length - 4, 4),
                    Icon = ListPath[i]
                });
            }

            lvMaster.ItemsSource = Items;
        }

 public class ExplorerData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public object Icon { get; set; }
    }
```